# i want to connect react js registration app from my sql database in which data store

Tags: mysql, reactjs

it is the registration form code. i want to store this form data in mysql database

```
            import React, { Component } from "react";
            import './Form.css'
            import MuiThemeProvider from 'material-ui/styles/MuiThemeProvider';
            import AppBar from 'material-ui/AppBar';
            import TextField from 'material-ui/TextField';
            import firebase from '../firebase';



            class Form extends Component
            {
                constructor( props )
                {
                    super( props );
                    this.state = {
                        firstName: '',
                        lastName: '',
                        emailId: '',
                        dob: '',
                        phoneNumber: '',
                        password: '',
                        confirm_password: '',
                        formErrors: {}
                    };

                    this.initialState = this.state;
                }



                handleFormValidation ()
                {
                    const { firstName, lastName, emailId, dob, phoneNumber, password, confirm_password } = this.state;
                    let formErrors = {};
                    let formIsValid = true;

                    //first name     
                    if( !firstName )
                    {
                        formIsValid = false;
                        formErrors[ "firstNameErr" ] = "Name is required.";
                    }
                    else if( !( /^[a-zA-Z]+$/.test( firstName ) ) )
                    {

                        formIsValid = false;
                        formErrors[ "firstNameErr" ] = "Invalid Name.";
                    }

                    //lastName 
                    if( !lastName )
                    {
                        formIsValid = false;
                        formErrors[ "lastNameErr" ] = "Last Name is required.";
                    }
                    else if( !( /^[a-zA-Z]+$/.test( lastName ) ) )
                    {

                        formIsValid = false;
                        formErrors[ "lastNameErr" ] = "Invalid Name.";
                    }


                    //Email    
                    if( !emailId )
                    {
                        formIsValid = false;
                        formErrors[ "emailIdErr" ] = "Email id is required.";
                    }
                    else if( !( /^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/.test( emailId ) ) )
                    {

                        formIsValid = false;
                        formErrors[ "emailIdErr" ] = "Invalid email id.";
                    }

                    //DOB    
                    if( !dob )
                    {
                        formIsValid = false;
                        formErrors[ "dobErr" ] = "Date of birth is required.";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        var pattern = /^(0[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-9]|3[0-1])\/(0[1-9]|1[0-2])\/([0-9]{4})$/;
                        if( !pattern.test( dob ) )
                        {
                            formIsValid = false;
                            formErrors[ "dobErr" ] = "Invalid date of birth";
                        }
                    }

                    //Phone number    
                    if( !phoneNumber )
                    {
                        formIsValid = false;
                        formErrors[ "phoneNumberErr" ] = "Phone number is required.";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        var mobPattern = /^(?:(?:\\+|0{0,2})91(\s*[\\-]\s*)?|[0]?)?[789]\d{9}$/;
                        if( !mobPattern.test( phoneNumber ) )
                        {
                            formIsValid = false;
                            formErrors[ "phoneNumberErr" ] = "Invalid phone number.";
                        }
                    }

                    //password
                    if( !password )
                    {
                        formIsValid = false;
                        formErrors[ "passwordErr" ] = "Password is required.";
                    }
                    else if( !/^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).{8,32}$/.test( password ) ) 
                    {

                        formIsValid = false;
                        formErrors[ "passwordErr" ] = " Password Must contain at least one uppercase and one number and lowercase letter,and at least 8 or more";
                    }
                    //confirm password
                    if( password !== confirm_password )
                    {
                        formIsValid = false;
                        formErrors[ "confirm_passwordErr" ] = "Password is not matched.";
                    }
                    this.setState( { formErrors: formErrors } );
                    return formIsValid;
                }

                handleChange = ( e ) =>
                {
                    const { name, value } = e.target;
                    this.setState( { [ name ]: value } );
                }

                handleSubmit = ( e ) =>
                {
                    e.preventDefault();

                    if( this.handleFormValidation() )
                    {
                        alert( 'You have been successfully registered.' )
                        this.setState( this.initialState )
                    }

                }


                render ()
                {

                    const { firstNameErr, lastNameErr, emailIdErr, dobErr, phoneNumberErr, passwordErr, confirm_passwordErr } = this.state.formErrors;

                    return (
                        <center>
                            <div className="formDiv">
                                <form onSubmit={ this.handleSubmit }>
                                    <MuiThemeProvider>
                                        <AppBar title="Registerd" />
                                        <div>



                                            <div className="column">
                                                <TextField type="text" name="firstName"
                                                    value={ this.state.firstName }
                                                    onChange={ this.handleChange }
                                                    hintText="Your name.."
                                                    floatingLabelText="Name"
                                                    className={ firstNameErr ? ' showError' : '' }

                                                />
                                                { firstNameErr &&
                                                    <div style={ { color: "red", Bottom: 5 } }>{ firstNameErr }</div>
                                                }

                                            </div>
                                            <div className="column">



                                                <TextField type="text" name="lastName"
                                                    value={ this.state.lastName }
                                                    onChange={ this.handleChange }
                                                    hintText="Your Last name.."
                                                    floatingLabelText="Last Name"
                                                    className={ lastNameErr ? ' showError' : '' } />
                                                { lastNameErr &&
                                                    <div style={ { color: "red", paddingBottom: 5 } }>{ lastNameErr }</div>
                                                }
                                            </div>
                                            <div className="column">

                                                <TextField type="text" name="emailId"
                                                    value={ this.state.emailId }
                                                    onChange={ this.handleChange }
                                                    hintText="Your email id.."
                                                    floatingLabelText="Email Id"
                                                    className={ emailIdErr ? ' showError' : '' } />
                                                { emailIdErr &&
                                                    <div style={ { color: "red", paddingBottom: 5 } }>{ emailIdErr }</div>
                                                }

                                            </div>
                                            <div className="column">
                                                <TextField type="text" name="dob"
                                                    value={ this.state.dob }
                                                    onChange={ this.handleChange }
                                                    hintText="DD/MM/YYYY.."
                                                    floatingLabelText="Birth Date"
                                                    className={ dobErr ? ' showError' : '' } />
                                                { dobErr &&
                                                    <div style={ { color: "red", paddingBottom: 5 } }>{ dobErr }</div>
                                                }
                                            </div>
                                            <div className="column">
                                                <TextField type="text" name="phoneNumber"
                                                    onChange={ this.handleChange }
                                                    value={ this.state.phoneNumber }
                                                    hintText="Your phone number.."
                                                    floatingLabelText="Phone Number"
                                                    className={ phoneNumberErr ? ' showError' : '' } />
                                                { phoneNumberErr &&
                                                    <div style={ { color: "red", paddingBottom: 5 } }>{ phoneNumberErr }</div>
                                                }

                                            </div>
                                            <div className="column">
                                                <TextField type="password" name="password"
                                                    onChange={ this.handleChange }
                                                    value={ this.state.password }
                                                    hintText="Your password.."
                                                    floatingLabelText="Password"
                                                    className={ passwordErr ? ' showError' : '' } />
                                                { passwordErr &&
                                                    <div style={ { color: "red", paddingBottom: 5 } }>{ passwordErr }</div>
                                                }
                                            </div>
                                            <div className="column1">
                                                <TextField type="password" name="confirm_password"
                                                    onChange={ this.handleChange }
                                                    value={ this.state.confirm_password }
                                                    hintText="Your confirm password.."
                                                    floatingLabelText="Confirm Password"

                                                    className={ confirm_passwordErr ? ' showError' : '' } />
                                                { confirm_passwordErr &&
                                                    <div style={ { color: "red", paddingBottom: 5 } }>{ confirm_passwordErr }</div>
                                                }
                                            </div>
                                            <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
                                        </div>
                                    </MuiThemeProvider>
                                </form>
                            </div >
                        </center>
                    )
                }
            }

            export default Form;
```

it is the database connection file code

```
//server.js
const express = require( 'express' );



const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;

const app = express();
const Mysql = require( 'mysql' );
const connection = Mysql.createConnection( {
    host: 'root',
    user: 'root',
    password: 'root',
    database: 'testdb'
} );

// api here
app.post( '/register', function ( req, res )
{
    var post = {
        firstName: req.body.firstName,
        lastName: req.body.lastName,
        emailId: req.body.emailId,
        dob: req.body.dob,
        phoneNumber: req.body.phoneNumber,
        password: req.body.password,
        confirm_password: req.body.confirm_password

    };

    connection.query( 'select * from register', post, function ( err, result )
    {
        // send response here
        res.json( { msg: 'success' } );
    } );

} );

connection.connect( function ( err )
{
    ( err ) ? console.log( err ) : console.log( connection );
} );

require( './components/Form' )( app );

app.listen( PORT, () =>
{
    console.log( 'app running on port { PORT }' );
} );
```

1

How do I connect my reactjs to mysql? I already install mysql and I follow the common instruction to connect it but it doesn't work. It gets an error "TypeError: mysql.createConnection is not a function".

Comment: The question you asked is not concerned with a single small task. Please try to ask a smaller and specific problem. Kindly read stackoverflow guidelines on how to ask [good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and what [topics](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) can you ask about

Answer (score 0):

You should use NodeJS to connect to your Backend (https://nodejs.org/en/download/). If you have already installed NodeJS you can install the `mysql package` via `npm install mysql`